# Zend Rewrite rules aren't working

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I've set up zend this evening, and the default index page works ( http://home.mitheren.com/399a4/public/ ). I've since tried adding a new Action on that controller, but I keep getting a 404 error.

This is my .htaccess file for the public/ directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /399a4/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When I try to access the page ( http://home.mitheren.com/399a4/public/index/testing ) I get a 404 error and the following message in /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Mon Apr 30 21:44:30 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.254] File does not exist: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing
```

I've also tried rewrite logging, and on accessing that page get the following entries:

```
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9e6020/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] add path info postfix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php -> /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9e6020/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing -> index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9e6020/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php/testing'
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9e6020/subreq] (4) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/399a4/public/index.php' pattern='-s' => matched
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9e6020/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] pass through /var/www/399a4/public/index.php
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9cdf80/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] add path info postfix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php -> /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9cdf80/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing -> index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9cdf80/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php/testing'
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9cdf80/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/399a4/public/index.php' pattern='-s' => matched<
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:46:54 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9cdf80/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] pass through /var/www/399a4/public/index.php
```

The .htaccess file is definitely being processed (AllowOverride is on, and I checked by adding a variable and checking the php info).

UPDATE: Changing the rules to what Vytautas suggested gives me this output in the rewrite log:

```
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ddff0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] add path info postfix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php -> /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ddff0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing -> index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ddff0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] applying pattern '^/399a4/public/.*$' to uri 'index.php/testing'
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ddff0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] add path info postfix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php -> /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ddff0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing -> index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ddff0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] applying pattern '^/399a4/public/.*$' to uri 'index.php/testing'
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ddff0/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] pass through /var/www/399a4/public/index.php
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ec050/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] add path info postfix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php -> /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ec050/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing -> index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ec050/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] applying pattern '^/399a4/public/.*$' to uri 'index.php/testing'
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ec050/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] add path info postfix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php -> /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ec050/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/399a4/public/index.php/testing -> index.php/testing
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ec050/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] applying pattern '^/399a4/public/.*$' to uri 'index.php/testing'
192.168.1.254 - - [30/Apr/2012:21:59:14 +1000] [home.mitheren.com/sid#7f1ffd754120][rid#7f1ffd9ec050/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/399a4/public/] pass through /var/www/399a4/public/index.php
```

Update 2: For testing purposes, I added another controller (called test), ( http://home.mitheren.com/399a4/public/test ) which works perfectly. This means that my rewrite rules at least sort of work?

Update 3: Sort of solved!
I created more views on my second test controller, and they all work fine. It seems that I only have a problem with a redirect on my IndexController. I'm not sure if this is a real issue or my problem, but it will do for now. If anyone else has more information I'd love to hear it, but this should do to get my work done.

Answer (score 0):

`public` shouldn't appears in the URL. You correct URL is http://home.mitheren.com/399a4/public/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Sort of solved! I created more views on my second test controller, and they all work fine. It seems that I only have a problem with a redirect on my IndexController.

I'm not sure if this is a real issue or my problem, but it will do for now. If anyone else has more information I'd love to hear it, but this should do to get my work done.